# How do you get 'pause' stamps for a given audio file using google Speech-to-Text?

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

The output from google Speech-to-Text for an audio file is given below.

```
results {
  alternatives {
    transcript: "extremely grateful for the "
    confidence: 0.911402702331543
    words {
      start_time {
      }
      end_time {
        nanos: 600000000
      }
      word: "extremely"
    }
    words {
      start_time {
        nanos: 600000000
      }
      end_time {
        nanos: 900000000
      }
      word: "grateful"
    }
    words {
      start_time {
        nanos: 900000000
      }
      end_time {
        seconds: 1
        nanos: 100000000
      }
      word: "for"
    }
    words {
      start_time {
        seconds: 1
        nanos: 100000000
      }
      end_time {
        seconds: 1
        nanos: 300000000
      }
      word: "the"
    }
    words {
      start_time {
        seconds: 1
        nanos: 300000000
      }
}
```

I want to get the pauses between words. Below, the word "extremely" starts at 0 and ends at nanos:600000000. The start time for the next word "grateful" is Nanos: 600000000. But when we speak, there are gaps between words. I want the timestamps of the gap duration between words.

Is there any way to get this information using google Speech-to-Text?
If not, please suggest some alternative to be able to accomplish the same.